# JS MV* for single-page application with overlapping models

Tags: javascript, framework

I have determined that my homegrown solution for updating widgets on change is too buggy/hacky and want to switch to a framework. But which?

Background: It’s a small, but not too simple single page application that has a single server interaction step: It sends stuff via websocket, and receives progress updates and finally the computation result.

The important part is that it has a complex interaction model: After the initial processing, the user may click or hover several charts, whereupon a bunch of other widgets are updated.

Basically I have a global state that’s monitored and modified by many things, and those things should update only if something in their respective monitored part of the global state changes. The parts monitored and changed by each individual widget overlap heavily.

Which MV* makes this overlap of models least painless?